# Unexpected behaviour of interval shooting with Nikon D5100

Tags: nikon, long-exposure, timelapse, dark-frame-subtraction

I want to do some star trail and time lapse shoots this weekend and I have for the first time been looking into the interval shooting option on the Nikon D5100. I already understood that the interval time needs to be longer than the shutter speed so as a test I set the shutter speed to 30 seconds and the interval setting to 32 seconds. I said I wanted 3 shots.

I activated it and it took the first 30 second exposure, then seemed to sit around for another 30 seconds before taking a 2nd 30 second exposure and then decided it was done.

What I had hoped for was 3 x 30 second exposures with a 2 second gap between them. What have I done wrong to end up with such a big delay between exposures and then not even getting the requested number of shots?

Comment: Although it's a different Nikon model, this seems to be effectively the same question as [How to set Interval Timer on D7000 to take 180 x 25 second exposures with 2 seconds interval?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/how-to-set-interval-timer-on-d7000-to-take-180-x-25-second-exposures-with-2-seco)

Answer (score 2):

The sitting around for another 30s is called dark-frame subtraction. You can turn it off in the menu under Long-Exposure or Slow-Shutter Noise-Reduction , I do not remember which it is called on the D5100. Essentially, the camera takes another shot with the shutter closed to characterize noise and then it substracts it to give you a theoretically cleaner image.